# Why does WPF not render my colors properly?

Tags: wpf, blend

I apologize in advance if this question has been answered already, but I wasn't able to get anything with a few googles.

I have a photoshop image with an 8-bit color profile. I'm converting it into a WPF app using Blend. When I run the application, however, the colors I input are not the colors that are being rendered.

Specifically, the gray I have is #111111. This is what I have in Blend (BorderBrush="#FF111111"), and it's what I'm showing in photoshop. When I run the application, however, I noticed a difference in my colors. I did a screen-shot on the rendered app, and I'm getting #090909.

These are subtle gray tones, and it's actually having a very large visual impact on the application.

Is there something I'm missing here, or do I just have to guess at what the values "should" be until WPF actually gets them right...?

Comment: What are you using to show the color?

Comment: what is your screen color depth ? 24 bits ?

Comment: 32-Bit True color (Windows Display Setting). I'm using the window background (<Window Background="#FF111111" ...)

Comment: Make sure that the control that is displaying your image does not have any transparency set on it; or that you don't have a semi-transparent effect occurring over the top of your image.

Comment: It's the window itself, and there are no other controls. It has TransparencyEnabled, but the color itself has no alpha (Notice the #FF...). You can probably reproduce the test on another machine.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a standalone, simple as possible, application? If so, can you post the code and screens? If not, then there may be something else going on, such as another control *on top of* your border that has a semi-transparent brush applied.

Comment: Please confirm that the window's opacity is set to 1.

Comment: Hi Robear. Is there any answer for your question? because currently I'm not using blend but just putting the background color I'm getting by photoshop and it is not the same color!

Comment: Actually this was MY problem. When I pasted into Photoshop, I wasn't using the correct file type, so it was actually Photoshop that was changing the color. Try using the **Web** preset when creating the photoshop document for proper color settings.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is color-managed. If your WPF app is not color-managed your output colors will be different on a calibrated monitor. To fix your issue please convert to sRGB your image profile in Photoshop first. Otherwise you can implement color-management in WPF by using a nuget library such as Mscms.WPF

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

> Actually this was MY problem. When I pasted into Photoshop, I wasn't
> using the correct file type, so it was actually Photoshop that was
> changing the color. Try using the **Web** preset when creating the
> photoshop document for proper color settings.

<sub>Original: [Robear's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635688/why-does-wpf-not-render-my-colors-properly/77536398#comment52555802_11635688)</sub>